# What is the best way to map websockets connection to users in the database?

Tags: javascript, websocket, phpwebsocket

I am looking to map websockets connection with users in the database and have something like this at the moment:

```
function connectToNotifServer(){

var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');

conn.onopen = function(e) {
    alert("Connection established!");
    conn.send(JSON.stringify({user_id: sessionStorage.getItem("user_id")}));
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    alert(e.data);
};

conn.onclose = function(e) {
    alert("Connection closed!");
};
return conn;

}
```

I then have a PHP websockets server, that keeps a mapping of a connection to user_id.

However, I think there is a security flaw, as a user could simply inject any value he want in the user_id and impersonate another user. Is there a better way to keep this mapping, but without sending the user_id or sending it in another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Anything you send which is 'built in' to your javascript could, at least, be copied and duplicated. The only way to verify a user's credentials to the server side websocket would be for the PCP websocket server to require something like 'username/password' - which it then checks server-side and persists for that websocket only.
i.e. you would have to ask the user to input this info.